# How can I insert this objective function with these constraints on gurobi using java?

Tags: java, constraints, gurobi, absolute-value, objective-function

obj function: `min |Xij*Pij - Xik*Pik|  (i=1..10, j=1..4, k=5..8)`

constraints:

```
Xij\<=Tij    ∀i,j;

ΣXij*Cij\<=Bi   ∀i;

ΣXij*Cij\>=0.02ΣBi   ∀j;

ΣXij*Pij\>=S    ∀i,j;
```

I try this but it doesn't work(Infeasible model):

obj funct:

```
    GRBVar w = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "w");
    GRBLinExpr obj = new GRBLinExpr();
    obj.addTerm(1, w);
    model.setObjective(obj);
    model.set(GRB.IntAttr.ModelSense, GRB.MINIMIZE);
```

constraints:

w >= xir pir - xin pin

```
GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();         
for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {            
    for(int r=0; r<4; r++) {                
        expr.addTerm(pij[i][r], xij[i][r]);             
    }           
    for(int n=4; n<K; n++) {                
        expr.addTerm(-pij[i][n], xij[i][n]);            
    }       
 }      
 model.addConstr(w, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, expr, "vincolo " + count);       
 count++;
```

w >= xin pin - xir pir

```
expr = new GRBLinExpr();
for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
   for(int n=4; n<K; n++) {
       expr.addTerm(pij[i][n], xij[i][n]);
   }
   for(int r=0; r<4; r++) {
       expr.addTerm(-pij[i][r], xij[i][r]);
   }
}
model.addConstr(w, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, expr, "vincolo " + count);
count++;
```

xij <= tij

```
expr = new GRBLinExpr();
for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
       expr.addTerm(1, xij[i][j]);
       model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, tij[i][j], "vincolo " + count);
       count++;
    }
}
```

xij cij <= bi

```
expr = new GRBLinExpr();
for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
       expr.addTerm(cij[i][j], xij[i][j]);
    }
model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, bi[i], "vincolo " + count);
count++;
}
```

xij cij >= 0.02*bi

```
expr = new GRBLinExpr();
int budget = 0;
double value = 0;
for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
    budget += bi[i];
}
value = budget*0.02;
for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
    for(int i=0; i<M;i++) {
       expr.addTerm(cij[i][j], xij[i][j]);
     }
     model.addConstr(expr, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, valore, "vincolo " + count);
     count++;
}
```

xij pij >= s

```
expr = new GRBLinExpr();
for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
       expr.addTerm(pij[i][j], xij[i][j]);
    }
}
model.addConstr(expr, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, s, "vincolo" + count);
```